# Get different images for mobile and desktop with php, advanced custom fields without using js and ajax

Tags: php, images, css

I hope everyone is well!

I am looking for a possibility to load different galleries, background images etc for the phone and desktop. For example, I set my hero background image like this:

```
    <section class="hero" style="background-image: 
url(<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('advanced_custom_fields_field'), 'full')[0]); 
                                                                                    ?>)">
```

When the window is resized (or website is opened on the phone), I would like to get the image from another **advanced custom field entry** (for example get_field('advanced_custom_fields_field **_mobile**') )

Is there a way to do it in php without js and ajax or is it the best way to do it with js?

Is there maybe a way to include advanced custom fields in a styles.php sheet with the header

```
header('Content-Type: text/css; charset:UTF-8');
```

If this was possible I could just write media queries here and include different images with get_field() function, but I didn't find a way to access get_field() function in style.php

Of course, this all can be achieved with js, but I am curious if there is a WP way of doing this.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: hope you are aware of `wp_is_mobile`  function .

Comment: Thank you dear Anoop! This is great! No, I was not aware of this function, so this is a great help! It says in docs not to use it as a substitute for media queries but I will definitely try :D Thank you so much!

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I'm also interested in it, and there is no answer to it on the whole internet!

Answer (score 1):

You can display the selected image when using the `Image ID` return type

`<?php  $image = get_field('image'); $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size) if( $image ) { echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size ); }`

This function also generates the srcset attribute allowing for **responsive images**!

Comment: Dear Anoop, thank you for your reply. While this allows to get a different image size, it is not what I am after. There is a background photo that is in landscape and it works great in desktop version. When I resize to mobile, I need to load completely different image in portrait aspect ratio. I can't use `<picture> <source>` because the image I am after must be a background-image, not and img. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are after the srcset feature of HTML. IT allows you to define different images for different screen sizes.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Here's [a link to the W3Schools page on srcset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp) and [here is the Mozilla developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images).

Comment: Dear Matthew, thank you very much for your reply and links! The <picture> tag is sure very helpful but in my situation, I would like you use the css background-image option and set a full screen background using `style="background-image: url(<?php get image code here?>);` Also this background option needs to have background-attachment property set to fixed. Because I can't pass php variable to my style.css I do this with inline css, but I don't see how I can use a different image for mobile without a media query here... Thank you so much for your help!